# How to add items in list on button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Could you please tell me how to add an item to list on button click. Here is my code

https://plnkr.co/edit/hVQKk3Wl9DF3aNx0hs88?p=preview

```
var AddTODO = Vue.extend({
    template: '#add-todo',
    props: ['m'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            message: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addTodo: function () {
            console.log(this.message)
            console.log(this.m);
            //this.m =this.message;
        },
    },
});


<template id="add-todo">
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="m">
        <button @click="addTodo">Add todo</button>
    </div>
</template>
```

is there any way to add items

Comment: The plunkr you provided basically works... ;)

Comment: no when type anything on input field and press button click it will not add item in list

Comment: Yes it does (my browser is Chromium 58.0.3029.110). Maybe you want to add item after pressing the return key while the input is active?

Comment: how it is possible because I didn't push item in array ?

Comment: See your plunkr (https://plnkr.co/edit/hVQKk3Wl9DF3aNx0hs88?p=preview), file script.js, line 39.

Comment: @KrzysztofZbiciński it show `3` default items .but if you want to add more items than you can't do that .mean if you type anything input fied and click button then it is not added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153525/discussion-between-naveen-and-krzysztof-zbicinski).